# Computer Modern with Chrome

Tags: fonts, browser

When using Chrome, I'd like to enable the Computer Modern Roman to be displayed when I view math in, for example, physics.stackexchange or other sites that use MathJax.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Currently, my browswer displays such math in another font that I don't recognize.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Computer Modern font family and add it into your `~/.fonts` folder (create it if it doesn't exist. Restart Chrome, and you should see the font being used.

You can find them [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/). Unarchive with Archive Manager.

Also you can install the `texlive-fonts-extra` package (note that it has about 170 MB) which already contains those fonts. But it will also install you `texlive` binaries and maybe you don't need that.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: Hmm well I already have that texlive package installed, but it doesn't seem to affect the default font Chrome is using to display math via MathJax.

Comment: It might be MathJax can only use fonts that can be accessed by the browser, which would not include the texlive fonts. Can you try the first method?

Comment: Ok that doesn't seem to work either.